# Is it customary to omit or replace ‘head’ with ‘x-year / mile/ pound’ in the idiom “have a head start on sb” when the advantage should be quantified?

Tags: idioms

There is the following statement in Jeffery Archer’s fiction “The Fourth Estate,” of which I admit I’m a terribly slow reader:

> “The tactics made it possible for Armstrong Communication to declare a
>   profit of 90,000 the year he and Hahn (co-owner) parted, and a year
>   later the Manchester Guardian named Richard Armstrong Young
>   Entrepreneur of the Year. Charlotte reminded him that he was nearer
>   forty than thirty. “True,” he replied, “but never forget that all my
>   rivals **had a twenty-year start on** me.” - P359

I surmise “a twenty-year start on me” equals ““a twenty-year head start on me.”

Is it customary to omit ‘head’ of the idiom, ‘have a head start on’ by replacing it with a placeholder such as X-year / mile / pound/ class, and grade as used here, when quantification is required?

Comment: I must be honest - I'm not actually *certain* exactly what Armstrong/Archer meant there. I believe Archer came from quite a humble background - my best guess is that he means his fictional character didn't have the benefit of wealthy/influential parents for the first 20 years of his life, but I wouldn't like to bet the farm on that interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your surmise is correct - it means the same as "a twenty-year head start on me".

In my experience, it is not *customary* to omit the 'head' in that situation.  It actually sounds a touch awkward to me, but it is certainly a legitimate usage.  Consider [this definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/start_64#start_83) from the Macmillan dictionary:

> start (noun): an advantage that you have in a race or competition, by beginning it in a better position than the other people
>
> The women runners are given a 50-metre start.

Interestingly, Merriam-Webster does not seem to list this definition.  I wonder if it's more commonly a BrE usage?

Comment: I think it's six of one and half-a-dozen of the other. In Google Books, [gave him a few minutes **head** start](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22gave+him+a+few+minutes+head+start%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and the same without "head" both have a couple of dozen hits. It's much the same with similar search terms.

Comment: FumbleFingers. Though not exactly the same with ‘Six of one and half-a-dozen of the other,’ we have the similar saying, “There’s no big difference between 50 steps and 100 steps. This is the borrowing from Chinese maxim, 五十歩笑百歩- 'wu shi bu xiao bai bu' in the Mencius.- Emperor Hui of the State of Liang (BC 4 century) says: There were two soldiers who were defeated in a bottle. One retreated fifty paces and the other retreated a hundred paces. The former mocked the latter because of his retreat of one hundred paces.

Answer (score 2):

My "gut feeling" is that eliding certain words from stock phrases is more common than one might think.  Without having researched this gut feeling, I can at least give some examples of how stock phrases can "shrink."  Take two wrestlers talking to one another:

> "You have a twenty-pound advantage on me" versus  "You have twenty pounds on me."

Here, *advantage* is elided.  Or to stay with your "head" example, two weight-loss dieters who started losing weight at different times are talking, and one says to the other:

> "You have a 20-pound head start on me" versus "You have a 20-pound start on me."

Or how about two sophomores who decide to see who can graduate with the higher grade point average (with 4.0 being the highest possible GPA):

> "But right now your GPA is 3.85 and mine is only 3.80.  You have a [point zero five] head start on me" versus "You have a [point zero five] start on me."

To switch things up a bit, it's not unusual in American English to elide words from other stock phrases, perhaps not in the same way as in your example, of course, but as a sort of shorthand:

> "You know what they say:  'Hindsight is 20/20'" versus "You know what they say about hindsight."

Here, the speaker knows the listener will supply the missing "is 20/20."

Or,

> "You know what they say about the early bird" versus "You know what they say:  'The early bird catches the worm.'"

Or,

> "On Tuesday, Fred did an armchair-quarterback analysis of Monday's football game" versus
>   "On Tuesday, Fred did an armchair analysis of Monday's football game."

And so it goes.  Which reminds me . . ..

> Person A:  "How's it going?"  Person B:  "It goes" versus "It's going well, thank you."